# Tomcat not reconnecting PostgreSQL JDBC pools on DB restart

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, database-connection, jndi, tomcat8

Recently we had to restart our database server (yes, a production one), and one of the Tomcats didn't reconnect to the JNDI resources.

This is our JNDI resource definition:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/postgres" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://10.1.0.104:5432/db"
          username="******" password="*****"
          maxTotal="30" maxIdle="5" maxWaitMillis="10000"
          logAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true"
          removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
          validationQueryTimeout="5" validationQuery="select 1"
          testOnBorrow="true" />
```

Software versions:

- Debian GNU/Linux 8.2 (jessie)
- Apache Tomcat/8.0.14
- OpenJDK 1.7.0_91-b02
- PostgreSQL 9.4.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit

What could be wrong? Why it didn't reconnect automatically?

PS: This maybe is a cross forum question dba vs stackoverflow, but as it involves both side don't know actually where to ask it.

Comment: What is different with your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139235/tomcat-jdbc-pool-not-reconnecting-after-database-service-restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could happen on database server restart that the webserver connection pool become faulty or incapable of reconnect to the db. If you can't restart your Tomcat instance after the database restart (easiest choice) you should configure your connection pool to test, remove and replace your connections.
See the `validationQuery`, `testOnConnect` and `testWhileIdle` attributes in the [Tomcat 8 jdbc-pool guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes).

Comment: I already gave the `validationQuery`, but not the other 2 attributes